# Oidc-client: how to use signoutPopup method properly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, identityserver3

I'm wondering how to logout properly through the oidc-client UserManager `signoutPopup` method, without throwing an error when the user closes the popup window?

I'm calling UserManager's signoutPopup method and a popup window opens telling me that I've been logged out and I'm also presented with a link back to the application. Up until now everything works as expected.

Now, if I follow the above link, the application is loaded into the same window. Regardless whether I follow the link first, or close the window immediately there's an error

> 'Popup window closed'.

When the popup window is opened UserManager starts a timer that throws the above error if the window is closed before being cleaned up. I'm guessing that I'm supposed to clean it up somehow. Maybe, I'm just supposed to catch the error.

Does anybody know how logout with the `signoutPopup` method is supposed to work? I haven't been able to find any documentation or examples regarding this.

I'm using oidc-client 1.2.2, Angular 2 and IdentityServer 3.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, any help???